# Create additional pages library in publishing site

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

Does anyone know how to create an additional pages library within a sub site?

You seem to have all the other document libraries (document, form, picture, wiki) but not Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there is no template for the Pages library is because a lot more is required to support publishing pages. What needs to happen is that the 'publishing' feature is activated on the site - this will create the Pages library and other supporting artifacts. Note also that a pre-requisite is that a similar 'publishing infrastructure' feature is enabled at the site collection level. The latter provisions artifacts at the root of the site collection such as the master page gallery, content types etc.

Comment: just to clarify, the site uses the publishing template, I want to add another pages library.

Comment: Ah - only one Pages library per site I'm afraid. In SharePoint 2010 you can have subfolders in a Pages library which can help with structuring, but that's it really - otherwise you have to create child webs to structure/segregate things.